# Can wannacry or the wannacry 2.0 be halted or slowdown with only read rights for users set through active directory

Tags: windows, administrator, malware, active-directory

Let's say I have an Active Directory.

I'm setting up rules in the Active Directory, giving accounts limited access with read only.

Let's say now a wannacry ransomware lands through an email to a user's pc, will it be able to spread to my network as all my users have limited read rights and cannot write anything?

From my understanding, the answer would be no but as I've heard, wannacry does not need read permission to propagate.

Many thanks for any tips you might able to give.

Thanks.

Comment: Instead of going through all this trouble, why not just run updates to get the hotfix?

Comment: @Kaizerwolf imagine if tomorrow, we face the next ransomware that will flagged an unknown vulnerability, can that wannacry v2.0 be halted?

Comment: yes, ransomware can generally be thwarted by a lack of Write privileges. Most AV systems that provide a "anti-ransomware" feature restrict application's write access to files in selected locations. Note this has nothing to do with Propagation however, as WannaCry is a Wormable-exploit, and spreads by misusing OS features, so only OS patches can really affect it. But without write access, it can't cipher your documents.

Comment: @FrankThomas would you mind putting your comment as an answer, pls?

Comment: *will it be able to spread to my network as all my users have limited read rights and cannot write anything?* - **YES** It actually will spread unless you have installed the patched that prevents it from spreading.  How it spreads has nothing to do with read/write permissions on a share drive.

Answer (score 1):

It seems your question boils down to, "Do access controls prevent worms from spreading?"

The general case answer is "Maybe." Having access controls is a form of **defense-in-depth**, which means, it's one more barrier the malicious software has to break through in order to do whatever it's trying to do (spread to other systems, encrypt your servers, steal your data).

Usually, most access control systems have a mechanism that allows the access control *configuration* (i.e., what the access controls are; which users/IPs/objects are allowed/blocked; etc.) to be modified. The target of much security research (by both black hats and white hats) is therefore on the access control system's configuration mechanism, and what it'd take to obtain unauthorized access to change the access control.

So that's one way through: find an exploit that lets the attacker legitimately *change* what is allowed/disallowed to favor their attack vector. For example, obtaining privilege escalation to a domain control administrator would likely enable the attacker to change AD settings that would allow spread of their worm on network drives.

Another way through is to find an access control mechanism that can be bypassed, *even when it's being enforced*. This is the software equivalent of speeding horribly right past a cop, and even though the cop sees you, his car can't go fast enough to catch up with you, and you somehow escape justice completely, even though he calls for backup up the road.

So rather than changing a setting, if you find a vulnerability like that, the settings *don't matter* -- leave it "blocked" or "disabled" for all the attacker cares; he can effectively send a payload of data that somehow convinces your system to treat the attacker's data as if it's allowed or enabled.

If you have a piece of networked software with an unpatched vulnerability, and someone knows about that vulnerability, you're never safe. Since "zero-day" vulnerabilities crop up all the time, therefore, you're never actually safe; tomorrow a new zero-day could crop up that would take advantage of new exploits.

No access control can definitively prevent all forms of this sort of attack. The most reliable way to prevent something like cryptomalware from ruining your day is to have offline backups that are not in any way connected to the network. There are very few attack vectors that can successfully exploit weaknesses in physical security, and those that can, have to be very specifically targeted to individual facilities (stealing an authorized employee's badge and using it to enter through an unguarded entrance, for example).

There are other defense in depth mechanisms beyond access controls that can help (but are not a panacea, either). A Network Intrusion Detection System (NIDS), like Snort, can also help you, by detecting attack payloads on the wire and blocking them before they even reach your vulnerable systems. They use heuristics and targeted pattern matching to identify known or potential exploit attempts and block them. Many of these systems come with some sort of real-time update service, that will apply blocking rules to ward off known attack vectors as soon as they are detected, which can often be days or weeks before you're able to immunize all your systems with a software patch. They therefore reduce your window of vulnerability.

But no, all of the best security practices combined are completely ineffective against a properly targeted suite of exploits that take advantage of unpatched vulnerabilities. If this keeps you up at night, go write or buy an [EAL7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_Assurance_Level) certified operating system (and make sure not to run any additional software on it that isn't also the same certification level). It's the only way to be 100.0% mathematically positive that no vulnerabilities exist. (But even then, a user error could lead to misconfiguration that enables a vulnerability in the *configuration* to be exploited -- equivalent to having a perfectly secure door lock and then *leaving it unlocked* -- oops. It never ends.)